# Windows 10: Can't start ssh-agent: unable to open service handle on non-administrator user (OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9p1)

Tags: ssh, windows-10, openssh, ssh-agent, windows-users

I have two users on the remote Windows 10 server (Build 10.0.19045.0) - controller (administrator) and worker (non-privileged user). The first user (admin) is able to use Microsoft's `ssh-agent` correctly. All services can be started or checked via `Get/Start-Service` commands, `ssh-agent.exe` and `ssh-add` work as inteded, etc.

However, when I execute the command `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe` on worker user, the following message appears:

```
unable to open service handle
```

No other details. Exit code 255. No logs. Nothing. Just that non-informative and almost non-googlable message. It worked until a few days ago, stopped working 2 days ago.

#### Update: Workarund

I've found a dangerous and unwanted workaround by granting worker user administrator privileges, but as I understand, this should not be the requirement.